# BibTeX URL problem

Tags: bibtex

I have two questions/problems for which I couldn't find any solution:

1) For some reason, I cannot use the same code for these two internet sources:

```
@misc{EvansHBR,
author = {Evans, David S. and Schmalensee, R.},
title = {Why Winner-Takes-All Thinking Doesn't Apply to the Platform Economy},
howpublished = {https://hbr.org/2016/05/why-winner-takes-all-thinking-doesnt-apply-to-silicon-valley},
year = {2016},
note = {[2016.11.03]}
```

and

```
@misc{EC1,
author = {{European Commission}},
title = {Prohibition Decision (Art. 101 Ex 81)},
howpublished = {\url{http://ec.europa.eu/competition/antitrust/cases/dec_docs/34579/34579_1889_2.pdf}},
year = {2007},
note = {[2016.12.15]}
```

Notice how the second one has `\url` in `howpublished`. When I try to remove it (and the appropriate `{` and `}`), I get this error:
[image]

If possible, I would like to remove the URL from all my internet sources, as this makes the text stand out in a way which I don't like. Any ideas what is causing this error?

This is what I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib,setspace,amsmath,graphicx,float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{times} 
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\bibliography{sqwg2}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

And [here](https://ufile.io/69cd3) the .bib file.

Comment: If you use `biblatex` you should use `url = {https://hbr.org/2016/05/why-winner-takes-all-thinking-doesnt-apply-to-silicon-valley},` If you don't like how the URLs stand out because they are in typewriter font use something like `\urlstyle{same}` (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53962/35864) for more on this).  (You should always treat URLs as URLs!) For your second question I would need to see a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of your document - the solution (and whether `mergedate` is available) depends very much on the style you use.

Comment: Also: For future reference: try and ask only one question per question. The two issues you raise here are only tangentially related and could easily be separated into two questions making it easier for others with the same problem to find the solution and for those trying to help you answer the question if they can only answer one.

Comment: Thanks for splitting off the other question. It would still be great to have a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we can see what `biblatex` style you use and check that our solutions work.

Comment: Thank you @moewe - I edited the question and will open another one for the 2nd question. Regarding the url = {https://hbr.org/2016/05/why-winner-takes-all-thinking-doesn‌​t-apply-to-silicon-v‌​alley}, when I use this, it ignores the "url" entry. Full MWE is coming, will need to filter a lot of things I think, since a lot it not needed for the bibtex.

Comment: Please clarify if you use `biblatex` (as your tagging and title both suggest) or if you are using BibTeX (note the absence of 'la') as your last comment and the picture of the error message seem to suggest. If you really use BibTeX and not `biblatex`, please retag your question accordingly and correct the title. My answer below assumed you use `biblatex`, I will remove or edit it if it is not applicable.

Comment: Sorry that I'm so slow.. still working on the MWE. Yes you are right, it's Bibtex!

Comment: Changed it to Bibtex (sorry I thought it's the same) and edited according to your recommendations).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't have bare URLs lying round in your document. URLs may contains special characters that cause problems for TeX. Your first example URL is fine, but the second one contains `_` which is special for TeX.

So with your bibliography style and the `howpublished` field you definitely need the `\url{...}` (from the `url` package) in the second example, and you should have it in the first example as well.

```
@misc{EvansHBR,
  author       = {Evans, David S. and Schmalensee, R.},
  title        = {Why Winner-Takes-All Thinking Doesn't Apply to the Platform Economy},
  year         = {2016},
  howpublished = {\url{https://hbr.org/2016/05/why-winner-takes-all-thinking-doesnt-apply-to-silicon-valley} [{2016-11-03]},
}

@misc{EC1,
  author       = {{European Commission}},
  title        = {Prohibition Decision (Art. 101 Ex 81)},
  year         = {2007},
  howpublished = {\url{http://ec.europa.eu/competition/antitrust/cases/dec_docs/34579/34579_1889_2.pdf} [2016-12-15]},
}
```

---

If you were to use `biblatex`, however, you shouldn't use `howpublished` for the URL and `note` for the date of access. `biblatex` has dedicated fields for URLs, DOIs and the access date: `doi`, `url`, `urldate`, ... Those fields should contain the bare URI without additional markup. In particular there you should not use `\url`.

```
@misc{EvansHBR,
  author  = {Evans, David S. and Schmalensee, R.},
  title   = {Why Winner-Takes-All Thinking Doesn't Apply to the Platform Economy},
  year    = {2016},
  url     = {https://hbr.org/2016/05/why-winner-takes-all-thinking-doesnt-apply-to-silicon-valley},
  urldate = {2016-11-03},
}

@misc{EC1,
  author  = {{European Commission}},
  title   = {Prohibition Decision (Art. 101 Ex 81)},
  year    = {2007},
  url     = {http://ec.europa.eu/competition/antitrust/cases/dec_docs/34579/34579_1889_2.pdf},
  urldate = {2016-12-15},
}
```

If you don't like the typewriter font you get for URLs by default, refer to [Why are URLs typeset with monospace fonts by default?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53962/35864) and use for example `\urlstyle{same}`.