# How to use the url command in a .bib file with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, urls, overleaf

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345175/bibtex-url-problem) question, the top answers suggests using the url package within a .bib file.

I am using Overleaf and I am trying to include the url command in my .bib file, but it is just being printed out as plain text.

For example in the file `references.bib`:

```
@article{sensorSum,
    author = "Donghai Guan and Tinghuai Ma and Weiwei Yuan and Young-Koo Lee and A. M. Jehad Sarkar",
    title = "Review of Sensor-based Activity Recognition Systems",
    journal = "IETE Technical Review",
    volume = "28",
    year = "2011",
    DOI = {\url{https://doi.org/10.4103/0256-4602.85975}}
}
```

gets printed in my bibliography as:

> [3]    D. Guan, T. Ma, W. Yuan, Y.-K. Lee, and A. M. J. Sarkar, “Review of sensor-based activity recognition systems,” IETE Technical Review, vol.  28,  2011. DOI:\url{https://doi.org/10.4103/0256- 4602.85975}.

Here is the (shortened) tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[style=ieee,citestyle=ieee,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    Lots of text
    ...
    \cite{sensorSum}
    \newpage
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `\url` for the `doi` or `url` fields in `biblatex`. And only include the DOI and not the entire link in the `doi` field. `DOI = {10.4103/0256-4602.85975}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All URI/verbatim-like fields (that includes `url`, `doi` and `eprint`) in `biblatex` should only contain the bare URI and no additional markup like `\url`. Additional macros in these fields may be interpreted incorrectly and can result in undesirable or wrong output and possibly even errors if things go really bad.

The `doi` field in particular should only contain the bare DOI and not the entire link, so the correct input would be

```
@article{sensorSum,
  author  = {Donghai Guan and Tinghuai Ma and Weiwei Yuan
             and Young-Koo Lee and A. M. Jehad Sarkar},
  title   = {Review of Sensor-based Activity Recognition Systems},
  journal = {IETE Technical Review},
  volume  = {28},
  year    = {2011},
  doi     = {10.4103/0256-4602.85975},
}
```

The output will automatically be linked to the correct URL if `hyperref` is loaded.