# \textit makes link incorrect

Tags: urls

I want to make a reference in my thesis work and I want to make a link to a source using \textit

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{hinton} 
Jeffrey Hinton(2012)  
\textit{Neural Networks for Machine Learning}
[\textit{Lecture 3.4 — The backpropagation algorithm}] 
\\\textit{https://github.com/mebusy/notes/blob/master/dev_notes/NeuralNetworks.md} 
\end{thebibliography}
```

But it transformes https://github.com/mebusy/notes/blob/master/dev_notes/NeuralNetworks.md link(which is correct) to this one https://github.com/mebusy/notes/blob/master/devnotes=NeuralNetworks:md (which is incorrect. How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**
I added `\url`, but then he link doesn't work:

```
\bibitem{hinton} 
Jeffrey Hinton(2012)  
\textit{Neural Networks for Machine Learning}
[\textit{Lecture 3.4 — The backpropagation algorithm}] 
\\\textit{\url https://github.com/mebusy/notes/blob/master/dev_notes/NeuralNetworks.md}
```

Comment: Links should be typeset with `url`'s/`hyperref`'s `\url` command. If you insist on writing URLs in italic, set `\urlstyle{same}` and put an `\textit` around it (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53962/35864)

Comment: @moewe I updated the post. Please have a look

Comment: `\url` is not a switch. It takes the URL as an argument (between curly braces): `\textit{\url{https://github.com/mebusy/notes/blob/master/dev_notes/NeuralNetworks.md}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would rework your setup. It's basically identical to what @moewe suggests in earlier comments. Note that it's important to load both the `url` and the `hyperref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} % choose a suitable color for URLs
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{hinton} 
Jeffrey Hinton (2012)  
\textit{Neural Networks for Machine Learning. 
Lecture 3.4---The backpropagation algorithm} \\ 
\textit{\url{https://github.com/mebusy/notes/blob/master/dev_notes/NeuralNetworks.md}}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, the reason

```
\textit{\url https:... }
```

doesn't work is that `\url` expects to get a braces-delimited argument. Because you fail to provide these braces, the argument of `\url` ends up being the single letter `h`, *not* the entire URL string.

Comment: That space in `Jeffrey Hinton (2012)` was much needed. And the Unicode em-dash in `Lecture 3.4 — The` also made me cringe... (although that might just be old habits)