# Biblatex errors, IEEE citation

Tags: biblatex

I'm having some trouble with Biblatex.

This is a compileable version of my document:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\newcolumntype{~}{!{\hrule width 1pt}}
\newcommand\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\title{Übung}
\author{Phil}
%in the preamble for Bibliography
%--------------------------------
 \usepackage[
  backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}
%--------------------------------


\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text is to apper here. Yesterday... \cite{underwood_Test} now the usual 
text continues.

But what does this actually mean?

Bring me one of these big bags... not the individual wrapped ones, the whole 
big bag. That's the one I want. Business as usual... Disguting.


\newpage
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I'm getting this error and cannot find its cause by myself.
Process started

`This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: mydocument.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file mydocument.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file mydocument.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file mydocument.aux (There were 3 error messages) Process exited with error(s)`

Comment: You need to run Biber instead of BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 for a short explanation of the differences between BibTeX and Biber and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for an explanation of what the two do. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 shows how you can set your editor up for Biber.

Comment: Did the links help? Could you get your example to compile with Biber?

Comment: Any news here? At the moment this question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 and I will vote to close as duplicate if there is no protest in due time.

Comment: Yes, it did work once I used biber and followed the steps. However, I still haven't figured out where I can change the styles used to cite myself. I have not looked too hard though as the styles provided seem to suffice.

Comment: OK. I will vote to close as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 then. What do you mean by change the styles? Something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864 or the myriad of specialist questions on this site? Or do you mean just `style=authoryear`?

Comment: well all I wanted to do was change the url font to a unispace font as I personally think ti's more pleasing to look at and seems more organized. However I'm actually supposed to use the default font so I havent't even tried. I will save the link you provided as valuable resource for the future. thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Usually the URLs typeset with `\url` are typeset in a monospace/typerwriter font (`biblatex` typesets the contents of the `url` fields using `\url`). You can change that with [`\urlstyle{...}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53962/35864).